clang-format indent variables between PPD
Anyone who knows to get clang-format handle this:
#ifdef SOMEPREDEF
    uint32_t int1 = 333;
    uint32_t int2 = 444;
#else
    uint32_t int1 = 222;
    uint32_t int2 = 555;
#endif

instead of this:
#ifdef SOMEPREDEF
uint32_t int1 = 333;
uint32_t int2 = 444;
#else
uint32_t int1 = 222;
uint32_t int2 = 555;
#endif

The IndentPPDirectives seems to work fine for PPD's where you can define before or after the hash...
Thanks in advance!
